# Rotating icon if clicked on list item with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

So for My navbar I want to let my arrow rotate 180 degrees when clicked, although I have tried many things with CSS or JavaScript, I don't know what is the most efficient way to go about this. The icon I chose is imported from font-awesome.

I tried implementing javascript to get it done, didn't figure it out yet. Should CSS do the trick or do am I doing something majorly wrong here?

```js
const acc = document.getElementsByClassName("switch");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("iconUp");
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600;626&display=swap');

body {
    display:block;
    margin:8px;
}

li, a {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600px;
    color:black;
}

header {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding:10px 10%;
}


.Nav_links {
    list-style: none;
}

.Nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.Nav_links li, a:hover {
    transition: 400ms;
    color:grey;
}

#Login_nav {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    gap:1rem;
}

.switchIconRotate {
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
  }

.iconUp .fa-solid {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
#Demobutton {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #4EC843;
    border-radius:34px;
    border:none;
    color: white;
    width:130px;
    height:35px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:600px;
    font-size:14px;
}

#Demobutton:hover {
    background-color: #20D62C;
    transition:800ms;
  }

#Navbarline {
    width:80%;
    border-width:1.5px;
    opacity:15%;
}
```

```html
        <header>
          <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98d94e81b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo_image.svg" alt="logo">  <!-- Svg needs to work -->
            <nav> <!-- Navigation menu -->
                <ul class="Nav_links">
                    <li><a class="switch" href="#">Features <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down switchIconRotate"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>
            <div id="Login_nav">
        <a href="#">Login</a> 
        <a href="#"><button id="Demobutton">Get demo</button></a> 
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: I don't see arrows. Please make sure the snippet demo shows your problem.

Comment: Where exactly is the arrow you talked about on your navbar?

Comment: I think it should be visible now

Comment: The arrow next to features?? It works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I added a tiny js script and 2 css class. Also changed the icon to an arrow so you can see it moving.

```js
document.querySelector('#Demobutton').addEventListener("click",
(e)=>{
  document.querySelector('header .logo').classList.toggle('rotate');
}, false)
```

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600;626&display=swap');

    body {
        display:block;
        margin:8px;
    }

    li, a {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:600px;
        color:black;
    }

    header {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
        align-items:center;
        padding:10px 10%;
    }


    .Nav_links {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .Nav_links li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }

    .Nav_links li, a:hover {
        transition: 400ms;
        color:grey;
    }

    #Login_nav {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        gap:1rem;
    }

    .switchIconRotate {
        transform-origin: center;
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
      }

    .iconUp .fa-solid {
        transform-origin: center;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
      
    #Demobutton {
        cursor:pointer;
        background-color: #4EC843;
        border-radius:34px;
        border:none;
        color: white;
        width:130px;
        height:35px;
        font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-weight:600px;
        font-size:14px;
    }

    #Demobutton:hover {
        background-color: #20D62C;
        transition:800ms;
      }

    #Navbarline {
        width:80%;
        border-width:1.5px;
        opacity:15%;
    }


/*my code*/
img.logo {
    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
img.logo.rotate {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
            <header>
              <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98d94e81b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <img class="logo" src="https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/02-arrow-direction/arrow-left.svg" alt="logo">  <!-- Svg needs to work -->
                <nav> <!-- Navigation menu -->
                    <ul class="Nav_links">
                        <li><a class="switch" href="#">Features <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down switchIconRotate"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                </nav>
                <div id="Login_nav">
            <a href="#">Login</a> 
            <a href="#"><button id="Demobutton">Get demo</button></a> 
                </div>
            </header>
```